# Fixing a sed Command to Include Characters Conditionally

Tags: sed

How can I improve `pwd | sed -e 's/.*\/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)/...\1\/\2\/\3/'` to only return the ellipsis if `pwd` is greater than three levels deep?

The goal is to avoid `...home/example/foo`, but still receive `...example/foo/bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pwd | sed -e 's/\/.*\/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)/...\1\/\2\/\3/'
```

A tip for readability is to use another regex delimiter character when you need to use a lot of slashes:

```
pwd | sed -e 's#/.*/\(.*\)/\(.*\)/\(.*\)#...\1/\2/\3#'
```

Comment: read his question again man.  By the way, sed -r would make it neater he can replace his \\( with (  but look at what he's asking.

Comment: @barlop: It works here. I get `/home/daniel/foo` but `...daniel/foo/bar`, which seems to be exactly what he wants. At a first glance I think it is you who should read the question again. EDIT: at a second, third and fourth glance, I still think it is you who should read the question again :-)

Comment: @barlop: No. In his example he would have gotten the ellipsis if `pwd` was >=3 levels deep, he wanted this to be changed to >3. Try the command locally to see how it behaves. EDIT: This answered a now removed comment.

Comment: sorry.. you're right. you fixed it functionally and made it neater

Comment: @barlop: No worries. At least here it's very early, so I might have written _anything_ at this point of day, so you have every reason to be suspicious :-D

Comment: @DanielAndersson Cheers mate, that's exactly what I was looking for. Also, thanks for the tip on cleaning up the syntax.